# How to remove odd characters in R wordcloud

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

I'm trying to build a word cloud in R using corpus and various tm_map functions. The problem is I keep getting this odd symbol returned, the one with the euro symbol and the upside down quotes. It's coming up as second most frequent in my corpus. (There are one or two others but they're nowhere near as frequent so less of a problem.)

[Word cloud with rogue €“](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpywm.jpg)

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

This is a sample of the text in .txt format before it is pulled into R:

> The move to Virtual Replication 6 added replication in and out of AWS where that had only previously been one-way, into the Amazon cloud storage platform. 
>   It had taken longer to develop in AWS, said Zerto technology evangelist Gjisbert Janssen van Doorn. “Bi-directional replication to and from Azure was where we started. We try to develop natively via APIs for the clouds we support but that had taken longer with AWS.” Zerto has also added bi-directional replication with IBM Cloud. van Doorn said the company had no plan to add support for Google Cloud Platform. “It’s something we’re keeping an eye on. It’s on the wishlist rather than the roadmap,” he said.

This is how it comes out after being pulled in to R via Corpus():

> The move to Virtual Replication 6 added replication in and out of AWS where that had only previously been one-way, into the Amazon cloud storage platform.\n\nIt had taken longer to develop in AWS, said Zerto technology evangelist Gjisbert Janssen van Doorn. â€œBi-directional replication to and from Azure was where we started. We try to develop natively via APIs for the clouds we support but that had taken longer with AWS.â€\u009d\n\nZerto has also added bi-directional replication with IBM Cloud. van Doorn said the company had no plan to add support for Google Cloud Platform. â€œItâ€™s something weâ€™re keeping an eye on. Itâ€™s on the wishlist rather than the roadmap,â€\u009d he said.

Then I run this code:

```
# Convert the text to lower case
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
# Remove numbers
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
# Remove english common stopwords
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
# Remove punctuations
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
# Remove your own stop word
# specify your stopwords as a character vector
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("new", "products", "way", "back", 
"can", "need", "also", "Ã¢", "look", "will", "one", "right",
                                    "move", "gorge", "mathieu", "like", 
"said", "€“", "â€“", "â", "data",
                                    "use", "storage"))
# Remove punctuations
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
# Eliminate extra white spaces
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
```

After that the same body of text looks like this:

> virtual replication added replication aws previously oneway amazon cloud platform taken longer develop aws zerto technology evangelist gjisbert janssen van doorn €œbidirectional replication azure started try develop natively via apis clouds support taken longer awsâ€\u009d zerto added bidirectional replication ibm cloud van doorn company plan add support google cloud platform €œitâ€™s something weâ€™re keeping eye itâ€™s wishlist rather roadmap

So, those tm_map functions haven't got rid of all the junk so the word cloud I run from this still contains them.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you add a sample of the text used to make the wordcloud? Or data table?

Comment: I've added post-Corpus() text sample and code used to remove custom stopwords.

Comment: Please add a pre-Corpus text sample and the code until you got to the part or the custom stopwords function. The problem might not be connected with the stopword removal, but from earlier processing steps.

Comment: Pre-Corpus(), post-Corpus() and post tm_map processing text added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using an extra package, you can use the `textclean` package, this works nicely in combination with the tm functions. This package contains all kinds of useful functions for cleaning text with weird characters, urls, emoticons, etc. For the example text you need to use the functions `replace_curly_quote` for removing ” and ’ characters and `replace_contraction` to replace "it's" to "it is". See a working example below. After all of that you can just use the `wordcloud` package to create a wordcloud.

```
txt <- "The move to Virtual Replication 6 added replication in and out of AWS where that had only previously been one-way, into the Amazon cloud storage platform. It had taken longer to develop in AWS, said Zerto technology evangelist Gjisbert Janssen van Doorn. “Bi-directional replication to and from Azure was where we started. We try to develop natively via APIs for the clouds we support but that had taken longer with AWS.” Zerto has also added bi-directional replication with IBM Cloud. van Doorn said the company had no plan to add support for Google Cloud Platform. “It’s something we’re keeping an eye on. It’s on the wishlist rather than the roadmap,” he said."

library(tm)
library(textclean)

corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(txt))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))

# function from textclean to remove curly quotes ” and ’
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, replace_curly_quote)
# function from textclean to replace "it's" to "it is"
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, replace_contraction)

# Remove punctuations
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)

# Remove numbers
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)

# Remove english common stopwords
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

my_stopwords <- c("new", "products", "way", "back", "can", "need", "also", 
                  "look", "will", "one", "right","move", "gorge", "mathieu", 
                  "like", "said", "data","use", "storage")

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, my_stopwords)

#remove created whitespaces
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

content(corpus)
[[1]]
[1] " virtual replication added replication aws previously oneway amazon cloud platform taken longer develop aws zerto technology evangelist gjisbert janssen van doorn bidirectional replication azure started try develop natively via apis clouds support taken longer aws zerto added bidirectional replication ibm cloud van doorn company plan add support google cloud platform something keeping eye wishlist rather roadmap "
```

Comment: My first run with the full corpus still has the euro symbol remaining; 555 times! Is there some way in textclean to cut out words of less than a certain wordlength? That would do the trick

Comment: I see you used VCorpus to bring the text in. I'm using Corpus() because I'm bringing in text from many .txt files. Is it possible the error has come in at this point?

Comment: There are differences between VCorpus and Corpus, but that shouldn't matter much in this case. You can use either when loading multiple text files. I get the same results either way. When you create a documenttermmatrix you can specify the wordLength in the control part of it. Default is 3, aka words with 3 chars or more. You can change this if you want. But I'm surprised you still have the euro symbol.